# Select 75 hz refresh rate from display settings

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution

I am using Xorg display drivers with my 75 hz monitor but there is no option for 75 hz. I tried using nvidia drivers, but the 75 hz setting causes keyboard input lag. Does anyone know how I can get 75 hz on my monitor with xorg, or eliminate input lag from nvidia drivers when connecting to an external montior?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what desktop enviornment you use, see
[this link](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/high-refresh-rate-monitors-linux/) to list and change to the desired refresh rate.
Perhaps you can share your display model/make, for more information.